# How can I reference a formula with an on going numbering?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, align, subequations

I work with LaTeX for long time and I used `eqnarry`. But that's obsolete so I gave `equation` and `aligned` a try. The problem is, that if I reference to my equation it shows the chapter numbering `(?)`, but it shows the incorrect numbering at the equations right side.

```
...siehe Gleichung \ref{form:casteljau}.
\begin{equation} 
    \begin{aligned}
    \mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k} + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \\
    l &= 1...n, i+j+k = n-l
    \end{aligned}
    \label{form:casteljau}
\end{equation}
```

That looks something like:

```
siehe Gleichung 2.6.2.
"equation" ____________________________(2.12)
"equation"
```

So I tried `subequations` and `align`. Now I get the correct numbering (2.13) in the text, but the equation doesn't have a number at the right side, as it usually does.

```
....siehe Gleichung \eqref{form:casteljau}.
\begin{subequations} 
    \begin{align*}
        \mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k} + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \\
        l &= 1...n, i+j+k = n-l
    \end{align*}
    \label{form:casteljau}
\end{subequations}
```

That looks something like:

```
siehe Gleichung 2.13.
"equation" ____________________________
"equation"
```

btw the underscore is not really there, but it deletes my spaces, so i used ___s
Could anyone give me the correct combination? Because alot of blogs say that this should work, but it doesn't. Anything else I can post?

here the compile master document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{showframe}

% German stuff
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % so can use Umlaut chars
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % load babel *before* natbi [english]
\usepackage[normal,small,bf]{caption} % normal, hang, center, nooneline, Large

% mathematical Symboles
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amstext,chemarr}
%\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\usepackage[bf,sf]{subfigure}
\renewcommand{\subfigtopskip}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\subfigcapmargin}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\linespread{1.3}            % 1.5facher Zeilenabstand

\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ulem} %dashuline

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}%nolist printonlyused printonlyused,withpage

\usepackage{wrapfig}

% citations
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib} 

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{ifpdf}      % detect outputstyle

% Free Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%first[]-> even pages; second [] -> odd pages
\lfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\nouppercase\sc\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\chead{}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\nouppercase\sc\leftmark}} 


% Color in Document
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}       %define colored backgrounds for tables
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,1.0}
\definecolor{yac}{rgb}{0.0,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{middlegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

\usepackage{array}

\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png,.gif}
  \pdfcompresslevel=9
  \pdfpageheight=290mm
  \pdfpagewidth=210mm
  \usepackage[          % hyperref should be last package loaded
    pdftex,
    bookmarks,
    bookmarksnumbered,
    linktocpage,
    pagebackref,
    pdfview={Fit},
    pdfstartview={Fit},
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,    % open bookmarks in Acrobat
  ]{hyperref}           % for Querverweise
  \usepackage{bookmark}
\else                      % latex
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.ps}
\fi

\usepackage{epstopdf} %gordon: for displaying eps images

\lstset{
 backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
 tabsize=4,
 rulecolor=,
 emph={a,b,c},
 language=c++,
 basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
 upquote=true, %compile with pdflatex
 aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
 columns=fixed,
 showstringspaces=false,
 extendedchars=true,
 breaklines=true,
 prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
 frame=tlrb,
 numbers=left,
 numberstyle=\tiny,
 showtabs=false,
 showspaces=false,
 showstringspaces=false,
 identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
 keywordstyle=\bfseries\ttfamily\color{orange}, 
 stringstyle=\color{middlegray}\ttfamily, 
 commentstyle=\color{yac}\ttfamily,
}

\setlength{\parskip}{3pt plus 1pt minus 0pt}       % vert. space before a paragraph

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}        % lowest section level entered in ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}     % lowest section level still numbered


% --- Start of Document ----------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}       %roemische ziffern
\pagestyle{plain}       % Initialize Header and Footer

\include{title}         % Title Page
\include{empty}         % Empty Page
\include{affidavit}     % affidavit
\include{abstracts}     % Englisch and German abstracts
\include{acknowl}       % Acknowledgements
\include{abbreviation}      % Abkuerzungen
\include{toc}           % Table of Contents

%--- Include your chapters here ----------
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}       % Initialize Header and Footer
\include{chapter1}      % Introduction
\include{chapter2}      % Background
\include{chapter4}      % Technische Umsetzung
\include{chapter6}

\pagenumbering{roman}       %roemische ziffern
\pagestyle{plain}       % Initialize Header and Footer
\appendix
\include{glossary}      % Glossary
\include{appendix}          % Appendix A

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please try to give the minimal working example (MWE) in which your problem occurs. Creating it is the first step in debugging and helps us tremendously in pin-pointing where the issue may lie. In particular it should start with `\documentclass` and not contain any irrelevant long formulae.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me if you want the equation number -- say, (2.13) -- to pertain to just the first line of the two-line equation structure or if it should pertain to both lines. At any rate, don't use an `align*` environment *inside* a `subequations` environment, as `align*` environments are designed *not* to show equation numbers.

If you want just the first line of the two-line system to be numbered, I suggest you use an `align` environment and use the command `\notag` to suppress equation numbering for the second line. If you want the equation number to pertain equally to both lines, I suggest you use a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment. Observe where the `\label` instructions are placed in the two cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}   % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{12}

\dots\ siehe Gleichung \eqref{form:casteljau}.
\begin{align}
\mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k}
      + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} 
      + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \label{form:casteljau}\\
   l &= 1,\dots,n; \quad i+j+k = n-l \notag
\end{align}

\begin{equation}\label{form:casteljau_new}
\begin{split} 
\mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k} 
      + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} 
      + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \\
  l &= 1,\dots,n; \quad i+j+k = n-l
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\dots\ siehe Gleichung \eqref{form:casteljau_new}.
\end{document}
```

A separate suggestion: Since your formulas feature both `1` and `l`, you may want to provide a bit more visual distinction between the two symbols by using `\ell` instead of `l`. The first group of equations would then look like this:

[image]

Comment: if I take your split code and use it in my document, it doesnt give me any numbering at the equations right side at all. and the equation is refered by the chapter number again... but I think the problem is, that I have equation and eqnarray in my document, it seems to me, that this causes the problems.

Comment: @Jinxi - If you take the equation/split example from my answer, insert it into your document, and somehow end up not getting an equation number showing up on the right hand side, there must be something going on in your document's setup that you haven't told us about yet. (Your document does load the `amsmath` package, right?) Please consider augmenting your posting to provide information about the portions of your document's preamble that do stuff related to equation numbering and cross-referencing. (Having an `eqnarray` somewhere else in the document shouldn't mess up equation numbering.)

Comment: yes I;m using amsmath. and a lot of other packages. I just added the master document, do you think an other package could block the correct numbering?

Comment: Small suggestion: `\newcommand*\Vector[1]{\mathbf{#1}}`. It makes a change of notation easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question. How about

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}  %numbering within chapter


\begin{document}
\chapter{a}

....siehe Gleichung~\ref{bbb}.
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k} + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \label{aaa} \\ 
    l &= 1...n, i+j+k = n-l \label{bbb}
\end{align}


\begin{align}
        \mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k} + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \nonumber \\  %without equation number
        l &= 1...n, i+j+k = n-l.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: shows 2.6.2 and no number at my pdf and I copied your code with the numbering... and did the \numberwithin stuff too. I have scrbook as documentclass that shouldn;t make a difference ?!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did some test, a combination with my code and your code, and the problem still occures. (sorry for my confusing way of writing...) 
I;m using pdflatex btw.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}   % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{12}

See equation tangentSpace0 \ref{form:tangentSpace0}, form:tangentSpace1 \ref{form:tangentSpace1}, form:tangentSpace2 \ref{form:tangentSpace2}.
\begin{eqnarray}
E_{V2-V1} = V2.xyz - V1.xyz =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  18 - 0\\
  18 - 18\\
  0 - 0
 \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  18\\
  0\\
  0
  \label{form:tangentSpace0}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
\nonumber\\
\begin{eqnarray}
E_{V2-V1} = V2.uv - V1.uv =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 - 0\\
  0 - 0
 \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0
  \label{form:tangentSpace1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
\\
\begin{eqnarray}
T_{unnormalisiert} = E_{V2-V1}.xyz / E_{V2-V1}.u = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  18 / 1\\
  0 / 1\\
  0 / 1
 \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  18\\
  0\\
  0
  \label{form:tangentSpace2}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

\dots\ your version: form:casteljau \eqref{form:casteljau}.
\begin{align}
\mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k}
      + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} 
      + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \label{form:casteljau}\\
   l &= 1,\dots,n; \quad i+j+k = n-l \notag
\end{align}

\dots\ your version: form:casteljau\_new \eqref{form:casteljau_new}.
\begin{equation}\label{form:casteljau_new}
\begin{split} 
\mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k} 
      + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} 
      + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \\
  l &= 1,\dots,n; \quad i+j+k = n-l
\end{split}
\end{equation}



...my old version with equation and aligned: form:casteljau1 \ref{form:casteljau1}.
\begin{equation} 
    \begin{aligned}
    \mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k} + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \\
    l &= 1...n, i+j+k = n-l
    \end{aligned}
    \label{form:casteljau1}
\end{equation}

...my old version with subequations and align form:casteljau2 \eqref{form:casteljau2}.
\begin{subequations} 
    \begin{align}
        \mathbf{p}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= u\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i+1,j,k} + v\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j+1,k} + (1-u-v)\mathbf{p}^{l-1}_{i,j,k+1} \\
        l &= 1...n, i+j+k = n-l
    \end{align}
    \label{form:casteljau2}
\end{subequations}


and eqnarry again: form:tangentSpace3 \ref{form:tangentSpace3}


\begin{eqnarray}
T_{unnormalisiert} = E_{V2-V1}.xyz / E_{V2-V1}.u = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  18 / 1\\
  0 / 1\\
  0 / 1
 \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  18\\
  0\\
  0
  \label{form:tangentSpace3}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

And this looks like the following image:
[image]

The numbering on the right hand side is so confusing. And I double checked the label names and reference names too.
It really look like you cant mix eqnarray with other packages... pls could someone just copie past that code and see if its the same result?!

Okay you can mix them, after compiling about 5 times it looks correct.

[image]

But If I try it in my work, after the 6th compiling it still look like that:
[image]
the lower equation doesent have a numbering and the reference shows 2.6.2 (thats the chapter...)

Comment: Do *not* use `eqnarray`, it is heavily flawed. See http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/madsen.html. Also those long names you have in subscript, you may wan to wrap those in `\textup` such that they do not resemble a long amount of indices.

Comment: And what is that `\nonumber` doing outside math?

Comment: Did you remember to compile at least twice?

Comment: XD I don;t know.. seems to me, I forgot that somehow! but removing \nonumber doesn;t make a difference in the image.
I know its obsolete... but now I have so many eqnarray formulas and I have to upload my masterthesis soon, so I will stick with eqnarray for this work, if I don;t use the other packages it's not a problem...

Comment: btw. nice link! I stored it, to remeber the problems for a new project :)

Comment: The article was written just for this sort of thing, listing why people shouldn't be using that construction. As far as I know even the AMS refers to it.

Comment: Look like what? What is the problem with the last image?

Comment: equation 2 doesent have a numbering and the reference shows 2.6.2 (thats the chapter...)

Comment: The code used is that, *exactly* the code you cite further up?

Comment: I took the split eqaution from mico. yes I used it in the test.tex example file. I copied from the file into my work.

Comment: Are you still having that `\nonumber` outside math? That may do strange things. Other than that I cannot help. I have no idea what is wrong with your document.

Comment: yes I already deleted nonumber. I dont know. but I will use eqnarray for this time. and the next document is clean and with the new equation package. thanks alot anyway :)